# Getting Object is Undefined Error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I recently did an Angular upgrade and I'm getting an 'object is possibly undefined' error and I cannot figure out how to get rid of it.  I've Googled this and found quite a few solutions but none of them are working.  I've tried using an 'if' statement to make sure the object is defined, null coalesce, inline null check, setting the question mark in the properties and yet it remains.  I'm pretty much dead in the water at this point.  This property should never be null.

Here is the code:

```
getDisplayClass(signal: Signal, signalHeadLocation:string, lightId:string): string {
   const signalHead = signal.signalHeads.find(signalHead => signalHead.location.toLowerCase() == signalHeadLocation.toLowerCase());
   return signalHead.lights.find(light => light.id.toLowerCase() == lightId.toLowerCase()).display;
};
```

The error is saying signalHead maybe undefined and lights maybe undefined.
Here is the object definition for SignalHead:

```
export interface SignalHead{
  lights:Light[];
  location:SignalHeadLocation;
}
```

If there's questions or anything else you need, let me know.

Thank you for your time,
Shaun

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the missing types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After everything is said and done, you're going to have to account *somewhere* for the fact that, according to the compiler, your `getDisplayClass()` function possibly returns `undefined`; either because it can't find a matching `SignalHead` or a matching `Light`.

The easiest way to go about that is to change the return value of `getDisplayClass()` to `string | undefined`, and in the rest of your function use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to account for the possible `undefined` values:

```
function getDisplayClass(signal: Signal, signalHeadLocation: string, lightId: string): string | undefined {
    const signalHead = signal.signalHeads.find(signalHead => signalHead.location.toLowerCase() == signalHeadLocation.toLowerCase());
    return signalHead?.lights.find(light => light.id.toLowerCase() == lightId.toLowerCase())?.display;
};
```